# UITextfield leftView as overlay

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to add an "error message" bubble that appears on top of the textfield when a user inputs incorrect values.  I've been using the .leftView property which works fine, however it takes up "space" in the textField, pushing content to the right.  What is the best way to display the leftView as an "overlay" rather than in the field itself?  (i.e. remove it's bounds)

```
class ValidatedTextField: UITextField {     
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // Defaults
    maxLength = 40
    layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(leftPadding, 0, 0)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Listen in on own text input
    self.addTarget(self, action: "textHasChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    self.addTarget(self, action: "checkTextValid", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // Add error label message
    labelMessage.frame = CGRectMake(10-leftPadding, -10, self.bounds.size.width-20, 24)
    labelMessage.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    labelMessage.text = "Message goes here"
    labelMessage.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16)
    labelMessage.textColor = .whiteColor()
    labelMessage.textAlignment = .Center
    labelMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.leftView = labelMessage
    self.leftViewMode = .Always
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create a bubble view and add it as a subview to your view controller?

Comment: That's true but I'm trying to make a custom UITextField that handles all of this separately.  It makes it much easier for form validation to separate all the code so I can use it in other places.

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: You need to make a custom `UIView` that contains a text field and some other things... not a `UITextView` probably...

Comment: @BlackSheep I attached the code I have above.  I currently set self.leftViewMode = .Always for testing.  The issue is that labelMessage pushes the actual text content to the right whereas I just want it to appear as an overlay without physical presence.  I'd prefer not to have it as a UIView because then all the validation events I have on text input wouldn't apply.  Unless I made it a UITextFieldDelegate.  What do you guys think?

Comment: @matt I could do that but it wouldn't show the actual error.

Comment: UITextField doesn't provide a property like frame for leftView so we can't change the leftView position. What you can try is to create a custom view lets say MyCustomTextFieldWithBubbleMessageView which will contain two properties a `UITextField` and a `UIView` this last view will be your custom bubble message it can also be a `UILabel`. Then u can use `autolayout` and display the bubble message accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

So I think I've figured it out.  By using leftViewRectForBounds and returning a zero CGRect I'm able to eliminate it's physical presence.

```
override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code that I suggested?  It works and the bubble appears in the textfield.  Please don't downvote unless you've tried the code.